# Exporting a dir treefile into a file

Tags: filesystems

I want to export all the filenames of a directory into a file.Is there any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: Is this homework?  Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can do this as `find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f > filenames.txt`. Without much more to go on, I can't really tell you much else.

What Operating System are you doing this on? Do you need to do it in some program or from the command line? Is there some format to the text file? These are things you need to include in the question to get better answers.

Comment: ok i am sorry.The files on the directory would be type .txt . I am going to do this action through a c program . The programm is supposed to implement this action both on windows and linux!